# How to add a power-on led in whis circuit?

Tags: power-supply, led, voltage-regulator

I would like to add a power-on led on this circuit (which is part of [this project](http://pmillett.com/ATEST.htm))

[image]

I would like the LED to switch off when the SW1 is in OFF position.
I was thinking of adding a LED in series with a 1500 Ohm resistor between pin 14 and pin 11 of DC1, but I am not sure this is a good idea, because DC1 would need to sink current and I think it can't (or at least I wasn't able to get this information from the [datasheet](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/1572/0900766b8157283a.pdf)).

Adding a LED between Pin 14 of DC1 and GND would cause a load displacement between the two outputs of DC1, or am I wrong?

Also please not that I removed U3 in my design, because I don't need +5V.

EDIT: As correctly pointed,  a LED between pin 14 and pin 11 of DC1 would always be switched on. I would then put it between pin 6 and pin 3 of SW1.

Comment: If you place the LED+Resistor between Pin 14 and 11 it will be always on, regardless the position of SW1. The negative output of DC1 WILL sink current. Still 1500 Ohm is a bit low in my opinion, you'll get about 20mA. You can use an high efficiency signal LED (basically, any modern blue LED) and it will be blinding even at 10mA.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and for the idea of using an high efficiency LED, which I will do. It's still not so clear to me how I can be sure that DC1 is able to sink current, is something this kind of components just can do, or am I missing something from the datasheet?

Comment: A negative output will normally sink current. A positive output will normally source current. Most of the regulators work only in this way. For instance, in linear regulators this is due to the series BJT, which can only "pull-up" when the voltage is below the reference value. They have no way to pull-down the output when the voltage is above the reference (the load will). Negative are just opposite. Buck regulators are the same: if you externally apply a higher voltage, the regulator cannot pull it down (at most can set a 0 duty cycle).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If you make an answer out of your comments, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect (as in your recently edits) the Resistor + LED, between pin 6 and 3 of your DPDT switch.

As pointed out in the comment, you should consider using a high-efficiency LED and a larger resistor value (e.g. 2700 Ohm) so that the current will be about 10mA, instead of 20mA. You might find that even larger resistors will give you a decent luminosity.

Like any other converters, DC1 is able to source from the positive output and sink to the negative.